# Como pasar parámetros a una ruta en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

yo en una vista estoy mostrando en forma de botones unos datos que se encuentran almacenados en una tabla de la base de datos, lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando le de click al botón me envié a otra vista donde se muestre los datos relacionados.

```
class Dimension extends Model{
protected $table = 'dimensiones';
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre', 'ies_id', 'vlr_dimension', 'propiedades_id'
]; 
}
```

con este modelo y utilizando el controllador traigo el nombre de las dimensiones y las muestro en una vista así:

```
   @foreach($dimensiones as $dimension)
    <div class="col-sm wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
       <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">{{$dimension->nombre}}</button>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

ahora, en la tabla dimensiones hay un campo que se llama "propiedades_id" y es llave foránea, quisiera saber como hago para que cuando le de click al botón me dirija entonces a otra vista donde se muestren las propiedades relacionadas a esa dimensión.

como hago para enviar ese id, a otra ruta?

Answer (score 2):

Bueno es muy fácil pasar parámetros de una página a otra. Simplemente tenemos que registrar la ruta y que controlador va a controlar esa ruta.

**WEB.PHP**

```
Route::get('/mostrar/{id}', 'Mostrar@Index');
```

Como puedes ver definimos nuestra ruta, pero tiene algo especial y es el id que recibe entre los **{}** esto significa que vamos a recibir un parámetro.

Entonces en nuestro controlador **Mostrar** tenemos que crear el método Index, ya que es el que estamos llamando, y este método va recibir un parámetro en este caso.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Mostrar extends Controller
{


    function Index($id){
        // En este caso devolvemos el valor del parametro, en tu caso necesitas hacer la query a la base de datos
        // y despues procesar esos datos y devolvermos a la vista.
        return $id;
    }

}
```

Y con esto ya podrías pasar parámetros de una página a otra. Hay más maneras de hacerlo y quizás te interesen mas. Te recomiendo que mires [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: gracias por responder, me podrias explicar ese controlador mostrar, es decir, lo que yo busco es que de una vista yo muestro los datos de una tabla, y después al darle click a uno de esos datos, se muestre los datos relacionados, por ejemplo, en la primera vista me muestra los equipos de futbol y después cuando le de click a un equipo, me mande a la otra vista y aparezcan los jugadores del equipo seleccionado.